# iPhone-SDK: pushViewController doesn't push UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

I have TabBarView Controller, where i keep four tab bar items, let sat item1, item2, item3 and item 4.
When clicking on item2 tab bar item, i call a RootViewController where it has a Navigation controller with a TableView and shows the row items.
Upto here it is fine.
When clicking on a row item, will have to launch a UIWebView to show the content.

I did code like below for this process.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:NO];
 [webViewController release];

}
```

The problem now is, clicking on a row item is not pushing the UIWebView code at all. I tested the UIWebView code with normal addSubView method like 
"[appDelegate.window addSubview:webViewController.view];"
instead of calling via pushViewController. It is calling UIWebView and shows the web content successfully.
I understand the problem should be calling as pushViewController:webViewController.

Can anyone point me what are the ways that it should be not be worked in this case and how can i correct it to make it work with pushViewController itself? I need to call UIWebView only using pushViewController.
For such all these combination, is there any sample source available?

Waiting for someone's help.

thanks.

Clave/

Comment: Is `WebViewController` a `UIViewController` subclass? Does it have a nib file associated?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistakenly creating a new navigation controller here

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
```

remove that line and use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:NO];
```

instead of your reference above.  That should do it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the problem of mine and resolved already, which is nothing but, i didn't set my particular controller class as 'Navigation' in I.B in Tab Bar Controller Attributes properties.